# UILabel Font and height in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I see that UILabel in IOS has height property along with font . I also see that if I give the height and font same value, for some characters the text gets cut in UILabel. How are these two different? While doing the UI design if height is more than the font size, there would be some extra white space which is what I want to avoid and hence wanted to know what exactly is the difference between the two.

Comment: just show  code of your lable ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sizeThatFits:` to determine correct height for `UILabel`

```
UILabel *label;
label.text = @"Some text";
CGRect labelFrame = label.frame;
labelFrame.size.height = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(labelFrame.size.width), MAXFLOAT].height;
label.frame = labelFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

The text size is the height from the font's baseline to its cap line, which doesn't take into consideration descenders (like on the letters 'g' and 'y') or ascenders (like 'f', in some fonts). In general, you don't have to (or even need to) set a label's height; it determines the best height based on its font size.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html for details about how font sizes work.
[image]